# Is there a way to catch all errors without littering my code with try statements?

Tags: android, error-handling

Is there a way to catch all error and do an action like display an error message in a Toast and restarting the application without crashing?

Comment: This is far too vague. And also no. You should address each problem itself not try to use some catchall.

Comment: **littering my code with try statements?** - Littering code with try statements is what a good programmer does. Handling exceptions, in particular specific exceptions, at each point in code, allows graceful handling of unexpected situations, allows for 'recovery' and in the majority of cases means the code will never crash (if you get it right).

Answer (score 1):

What we do is use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` to set a global handler on the UI thread. In the handler we get the stack trace and send ourselves a report, and then call

```
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
```

To restart gracefully